# How to solve the problem with broken pipelines after project export on GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a problem with CI/CD pipelines after project export.
I have a project with customized CI/CD pipelines that run on every commit and push.

I make export from GitLab 12.5.4-ee to 12.10.6 and I noticed that my pipelines don't run after commit to repository. On GitLab 12.10.6 everything works fine.
What could be the reason for this behaviour? How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? Check logs line. Could you please share the error if any.

Comment: I have no errors. Pipelines just don't start when I commit to repository.Where can I see logs of commit and push?

Comment: Double check your project's settings. Do you have CI enabled? `Settings -> General -> Visibility, Project Features, Permissions -> Repository -> Pipelines`